# How to list data from database for a backend module in typo3 extbase

Tags: module, backend, extbase, typo3-7.x

I am creating an extension with backend module in typo3 7.6.12. As a first step, I need to display the records as a list in the backend module. I just added the controller name, but no idea about how to write for a backend module listing. 
So how is it possible to list in backend module from database certain fields like name, etc...
Is there any simple extensions for references other than powermail?

Comment: Check this example extension https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/webuser. You can also use extension builder extension from [TER](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder/) to get started with extBase

Answer (score 1):

First, You need to register BE modules in your `ext_tables.php` file like below.

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'Vendor' . $_EXTKEY,
        'web',          // Main area
        'mod1',         // Name of the module
        '',             // Position of the module
        array(          // Allowed controller action combinations
            'Controller' => 'action, update, edit'
        ),
        array(          // Additional configuration
            'access'    => 'user,group',
            'icon'      => 'EXT:blog_example/ext_icon.gif',
            'labels'    => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mod.xml',
        )
    );
}
```

After Register BE Modules. You need to create Template folder for listing records and For use this template folder you need to add below typoscript in `setup.txt` file.

```
module.tx_blogexample {
    settings < plugin.tx_blogexample.settings
    persistence < plugin.tx_blogexample.persistence
    view < plugin.tx_blogexample.view
    view {
        templateRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        partialRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        layoutRootPath = EXT:blog_example/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation to be followed for export by xls/csv for a backend module in typo3?   What are the basic steps to be followed for an export feature?